# prepend **heredoc** to a file, in bash

Tags: bash, prepend, herestring

I was using:

```
cat <<<"${MSG}" > outfile
```

to begin with writing a message to `outfile`, then further processing goes on,
which appends to that `outfile` from my awk script.

But now logic has changed in my program, so I'll have to first populate
`outfile` by appending lines from my `awk` program (externally called from my
bash script), and then as a final step **prepend** that ${MSG} `heredoc` to
the head of my `outfile`..

How could I do that from within my bash script, not awk script?

**EDIT**

this is MSG `heredoc`:

```
read -r -d '' MSG << EOF
-----------------------------------------------
--   results of processing - $CLIST
--   used THRESHOLD ($THRESHOLD)
-----------------------------------------------
l
EOF
# trick to pertain newline at the end of a message
# see here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20042
MSG=${MSG%l}
```

Comment: NB: cat with a herestring? The portable way to do that would have been `printf '%s\n' "$MSG" > outfile`. Avoid bashisms where you can.

Comment: FYI, what you're doing here is necessarily inefficient -- "necessarily" meaning that POSIX doesn't provide any way (in *any* programming language) to prepend content to a file without rewriting that whole file. If it's a large file, then, you should try to avoid any process which would have you doing this frequently.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes you are right, in my script this occures only once.
I tried with that MSG writing being handled with  `awk`, but, as that `awk` script gets called more than once from within my bash script, putting that MSG into BEGIN block wouldn't help, because I would have many instances, and I want only one at the top.

Comment: As an aside: you can make do without `l` trick for preserving trailing newlines if you instead use the following: `IFS= read -r -d '' MSG << EOF ...`.

Comment: @mklement0 Would I have to revert it back to old `IFS` value, or it doesn't matter, because it would go with the script being finished?

Comment: No, there is NO need to restore the value, because prepending a variable assignment directly to a command that way _localizes_ it to that command - that is (loosely speaking), it automatically reverts to the previous value when the command finishes.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that, silly me. Thanks, your tip saves me two lines of code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `awk` to insert a multiline string at beginning of a file:

```
awk '1' <(echo "$MSG") file
```

Or even this `echo` should work:

```
echo "${MSG}$(<file)" > file
```

Comment: $MSG contains more than one line, it's a `heredoc` banner-like message

Comment: can you explain a bit, will this work only for that number of lines, so it will break if I change my `$MSG` to have more lines?

Comment: `MSG` variable can have any number of lines actually. awk's `substr` function has been used to strip off `$'` from front and `\n'` from end (those are added by `printf "%q"`). I have tested it on my OSX before posting the answer.

Comment: I lost my newline at the end of $MSG. Why is that, and how to keep it?

Comment: Sure just change `substr` to `substr(m,3,length(m)-3)`

Comment: I'm a little worried that this relies a bit much on implementation-defined behavior -- `printf '%q'` promises only to create a string that bash can parse, not to do it in any specific way.

Comment: Actually I couldn't think of any other way of passing a multiline string to `awk` earlier. But I have edited it now to remove `printf "%q"`

Comment: +1 for simple solutions, but you should note that (a) `awk` is not the right tool for this job _in general_ - it makes sense here _specifically_, because of the OP's specific requirements, and (b) the `echo` solution should only be used for _small_ files, given that the entire string is built up _in memory_ (right?). Also, it sounds like `$MSG` is already `\n`-terminated, so you should use `<(printf '%s' "$MSG")`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: To finish the discussion, even though `printf %q` is no longer in the mix: I share your concern; for instance, if the string happens to contain no characters that need escaping (though it will in this case), the result of `printf %q` is _not_ `$'...'`-enclosed. Note that GNU `awk` and `mawk` actually DO accept strings with embedded newlines on the command line - FreeBSD/OSX `awk` doesn't (which is actually the POSIX-compliant behavior). The `awk`-POSIX-compliant solution is to replace newlines with `'\n'` strings: `-v MSG="${MSG//$'\n'/\\n}". See http://goo.gl/uT1oh9 for more.

Comment: Highly underrated answer. Thank you! For the sake of completion, the `echo` version just goes to stdout - it doesn't rewrite the original file (per the question). The adjustment is simple: `echo "${MSG}$(<file)" > file`

Answer (score 5):

Use a command group:

```
{
    echo "$MSG"
    awk '...'
} > outfile
```

If `outfile` already exists, you have no choice but to use a temporary file and copy it over the original. This is due to how files are implemented by all(?) file systems; you cannot prepend to a stream.

```
{
     # You may need to rearrange, depending on how the original
     # outfile is used.
     cat outfile
     echo "$MSG"
     awk '...'
} > outfile.new && mv outfile.new outfile
```

Another non-POSIX feature you could use with `cat` is process substitution, which makes the output of an arbitrary command look like a file to `cat`:

```
cat <(echo $MSG) outfile <(awk '...') > outfile.new && mv outfile.new outfile
```

Comment: I cannot do that, because this happens in a moment when I already have outfile generated. I have a case checking if `outfile` exists, if it does, than I need to prepend my $MSG

Comment: I did exactly that: `cat <<< $MSG outfile > outfile.tmp && mv outfile.tmp outfile`, but ended up with `outfile` being empty, and still having that `outfile.tmp` in my directory? That was the reason I posted question here ;)

Comment: my bad.. now I saw, entered `>` between `mv outfile.tmp` and `outfile`, overseeing that, led me to post here.. sorry for taking your time

Comment: don't know why, but `cat <<< $MSG outfile > outfile.tmp && mv outfile.tmp outfile` doesn't prepend $MSG, `outfile` is there, but no $MSG prepended?

Comment: `<<<` provides standard input, and `cat` ignores standard input when it receives one or more filename arguments.

Comment: Oh, that was the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use `-` as a placeholder on the `cat` command line for the point where you want new content inserted:

```
{ cat - old-file >new-file && mv new-file old-file; } <<EOF
header
EOF
```

Comment: Can that `<<EOF` part, be replaced with `<<<"${MSG}"`, as I already have it that way?

Comment: +1 for the prefix form, but it's simpler to use `cat <<EOF >>old-file` for the suffix form.

Comment: @mklement0, indeed, that was silly. I've removed it.

Comment: @branquito, indeed, using a herestring there will be fine.

Comment: I like your answer the best, but not shure If would be now ok to accept it as I already accepted another one earlier, before you posted.

Comment: @branquito, there's nothing wrong with the current answer, even if this one is a little bit cleaner, so perfectly fine to keep it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said, your solution looks neat. Anyway I learned a few new and important things from all of you.